# Xcode 3.2.6 and Mountain Lion

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, osx-mountain-lion

I use Xcode 3.2.6 sometimes instead of Xcode 4 because I find some advantages doing that.
I had an old installation of Xcode 3.2.6 on Snow Leopard and updated to Lion and Xcode works as before. No problems at all.
Now I intend to update to Mountain Lion.
Now I have read about people having problems with Xcode 3.2.6 on Mountain Lion, especially Interface Builder.
Does anybody here have experiences?
May I continue running Xcode 3.2.6 on Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lars: Haven't done extensive testing yet but after upgrading to 10.8 Xcode 3.2.6 itself runs and seems to build just fine, including a PowerPC target. Interface Builder just bounces in the Dock when I try to launch it. This thread on the dev forums [Can XCode 3.2.6 & Interface Builder be made to run...](http://devforums.apple.com/message/705671) implies it could be issues with Xcode 3's iOS platform plugins.

Macmade: If you must support OS X 10.5 and below and PowerPC, which I have to, then Xcode 4 alone isn't an option. Keeping a copy of Xcode 3 around has been an ideal solution for those projects, especially as it will generally happily live in it's own folder hierarchy.

Believe me I'd love to avoid the hassles of supporting old OS versions but in the end what the client wants is what matters.

Comment: Thanks. That confirms what I already was afraid of. I also really need Xcode 3.2.6 for certain reason and especially the IB which is more flexible. Moving around in the window. What I am doing in some projects can be done in Xcode 4 but takes 10 times longer and gives a lot of errors by mistake. Since my Xcode 3.2.6 is already installed and went nicely after installing Lion I will wait with Mountain Lion. It is not as easy going back to Lion. Will stay this way at least until some projects are finished.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 3.2.6 seems to run just fine on Mountain Lion, though I haven't played with it extensively yet. And once I deleted the two iOS related .platforms folders in /Developer/Platforms (leaving only MacOSX.platform) Interface Builder works for me (and without the issues in the devforum thread).

I say its worth it to try and find out. I too need to support users that are using 10.6 support (I've only just dropped 10.4 support, and the next release will be dropping 10.5 support). I would have been up on Xcode 4 if they didn't drop 10.5 support when it first came out, and I would be on Xcode 4.3 if it worked until ML or Xcode 4.4 if it supported 10.6. But Apple made different decisions.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have now updated to Mountain Lion and IB just do not work. After removing the Simulator platform from Developer, IB opens up but are missing the plugins and it can't be used. And it can not open a XIB file

Comment: @Lars- Try uninstalling devtools and retry without installing iOS support in the first place. It worked well for me, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 3.2.6 seems to work, but I noticed some issues, like inability for apps compiled with it to access Keychains.

The most safe solution is to run Snow Leopard under Virtual Box. It's a bit slow to install, but it's manageable.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Xcode 3 on Mountain Lion for two months now without problems. Even the custom IBPlugin that the old project uses still loads and works.

The most essential thing to do is NOT to install iOS SDK, as its plugins break Interface Builder.

I've summarized all known issues into installation instructions:

- [How to install Xcode 3 on Mountain Lion](http://hamstergene.github.com/blog/2012-11-13-xcode3-mountain-lion/)

Answer (score -1):

Metrowerks CodeWarrior was a nice IDE, back in the classic OS days...

Seriously, you should move to Xcode 4.

Of course, you are used to Xcode 3.x, and moving to a recent version may take you some time, may change some of your habits.
But it's just the way it works.

Maybe you can use Xcode 3 on Mountain Lion. But just why?

Compiler versions are just old, you won't have access to the latest frameworks, SDKs, language features... Should I say more?

I don't think that developing an app on a modern system with a legacy IDE/compiler suite, just because you prefer it, is a nice way of developing stuff...

So just invest some time learning Xcode 4... It will definitively save you a lot of time developing/debugging...

Comment: That was not the question. I use latest version of Xcode 4 as well.

Comment: Then, why don't you simply **try** installing Xcode 3 on OS 10.8?

Comment: It would be great to stick with XCode 4 and up exclusively, but Interface Builder is required to edit Carbon NIBs. Even though Carbon is not deprecated. From the XCode 4.x Release Notes at Apple: "Functionality no longer supported in XCode… Editing Carbon nib files. Xcode 4 supports building Carbon XIB and NIB files; use Interface Builder 3.2 to edit them."

Comment: For those reading here later, xcode 3 won't install on 10.7 (installer won't run) without a hack.  And on 10.8 said hack actually causes a kernel panic.