# How to stop qmake from emiting certain flag

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I am using qmake on OSX with clang. I try to use c++11 with the following flags in the .pro file

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++
```

However qmake generates the follow flag in the makefile

```
CXXFLAGS = ... -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 ...
```

This flag causes clang to raise an error

```
invalid deployment target for -stdlib=libc++ (requires OS X 10.7 or later)
```

Changing the flag to 10.7 fixed the problem

```
CXXFLAGS = ... -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 ...
```

Is there any way to stop qmake from emitting this flag in the makefile?

Answer (score 0):

you can install other compiler for example gcc4.7.

There are few easy ways macports:
 1. http://www.macports.org/install.php
 2. Applications > Utilities > Terminal
 3. In terminal: sudo port selfupdate
 4. sudo port install gcc47
 5. Now add new compiler in Qt (Projects tab) 
 6. In profile change QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x

Other way brew:
 1. Applications > Utilities > Terminal
 2. In terminal: ruby -e "$(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
 3. In terminal: brew doctor
 4. In terminal: brew install gcc
 5. Now add new compiler in Qt (Projects tab) 
 6. In profile change QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x

Answer (score 0):

Specify the target version via `QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET`, e.g.:

```
QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.7
```

If you would totally get rid of the flag, you would get some message like:

```
ld: warning: -macosx_version_min not specified, assuming 10.8
```

So, your compiler will automatically add it anyway.

That flag is there for a reason. It's written into your binary. And when you try to load that binary on an older system, it will abort.

Now, if you really want MacOSX 10.5 compatibility, you cannot use `-stdlib=libc++` because that `libc++` is simply not available before MacOSX 10.7.

If you need `libc++` (e.g. some C++11 features) + you want to make it work on <10.7, that's not so easy. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494513/how-do-i-get-back-c0x-c11-support-for-mac-os-x-10-6-deployment-using-xcode-4) for a related question.