# Qt 5 cannot deploy on SnowLeopard

Tags: c++, qt, osx-snow-leopard, osx-mountain-lion, qt5

I have an issue where my app doesn't run on 10.6 Snow Leopard.

I compile with these parameters:

```
qmake LSPRO.pro -r -spec macx-clang CONFIG+=release CONFIG+=x86_64
```

in my Pro file, I have these elements:

```
TEMPLATE = app
HEADERS = \
    mainwindow.h \
    app_mediamanager.h \
    api.h \
    tool_htmleditor.h \
    tool_videoencoder.h \
    tool_thumbnaileditor.h
SOURCES = \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp \
    app_mediamanager.cpp \
    api.cpp \
    tool_htmleditor.cpp \
    tool_videoencoder.cpp \
    tool_thumbnaileditor.cpp

QT += network webkitwidgets widgets concurrent sql

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_X86_64 += -mmacosx-version-min=10.6
QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.6

ICON = icon.icns

RESOURCES = lspro.qrc
```

But even with a simple Hello world or the example files, it doesn't work...

I add the libraries with macdeployqt script.
When running on 10.6 I get this as error in the report:

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/username/Desktop/LSPRO.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/QtWebKitWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWebKitWidgets
  Reason: image not found
```

The question is simple: How can I target 10.6 from a clean Qt5 in 10.8?

---

### Update 1:

Thanks to the comments, it looks like 10.6 didn't shipped with c++11 support yet, causing the app to crash when looking for it. I tried 2 solutions:

**Failed solution1** : I rebuild Qt5 with the noc++11 flag, the resulting app starts on snowleopard but fails some inner elements Videoplayer missing in Qwebkit, unable to call external binary /execute command (app crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS) although the binary just runs fine when called directly and probably more undiscovered.

**Failed solution2** : I tried naively to include the missing dylibs (libc++.1.dylib and libc++abi.dylib) in snowleopard, but the app still crashes with the message :

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _NSPreferredScrollerStyleDidChangeNotification
  Referenced from: /Volumes/SANS TITRE/tests/LSPRO1.app/Contents/MacOS/../Frameworks/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
```

---

### otool -L of a 5.1.0 rc1 build

```
@executable_path/../Frameworks/QtWebKitWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWebKitWidgets (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.0)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtQuick.framework/Versions/5/QtQuick (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.0)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtQml.framework/Versions/5/QtQml (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.0)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtNetwork.framework/Versions/5/QtNetwork (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.0)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.0)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.0)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtOpenGL.framework/Versions/5/QtOpenGL (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.0)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.0)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtPrintSupport.framework/Versions/5/QtPrintSupport (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 19.0.0)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtWebKit.framework/Versions/5/QtWebKit (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.0)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtSql.framework/Versions/5/QtSql (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.0)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtSensors.framework/Versions/5/QtSensors (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.0)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtConcurrent.framework/Versions/5/QtConcurrent (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Versions/A/AGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 56.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
```

---

### SOLUTION:

ok finally got it to work.
Compiled Qt5 (5.1.2) on snowleopard from git (have xcode 4.2 with 10.6 sdk)
in my case simply with these config:

```
./configure -developer-build -opensource -nomake examples -nomake tests -qt-sql-mysql
```

I had to fix small elements in my code making the app crash without reason (variable names..) and then everything was ok.

Just don't forget to use the mac deploy tool on 10.6 and the app runs ok on 10.8 (untested on 10.7 but I assume this is ok.)

Hope this helps anyone.

Comment: If you look in the app bundle, does the QtWebKitWidgets framework actually exist in the given path that is shown by the dyld error?

Comment: Yes it's present. It's the one calling for libc++.1

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494513/how-do-i-get-back-c0x-c11-support-for-mac-os-x-10-6-deployment-using-xcode-4. Apple has decided to support libc++ only on 10.7 and higher.

Comment: Is there a way to deploy from Qt without libc++?

Comment: Any way to deploy on Snow Leopard by comping the app on 10.8?

Comment: personally haven't succeeded yet, I'm just working on 10.6 now. Works for me in this urgent project

Comment: Does Qt5 application compiled on 10.6 work correctly on any 10.7+ system for you? I have a problem that my Qt4.8.6 app compiled on 10.6 crashes on any 10.9 system when user executes application through associated file from Finder.

Comment: I havent't tried associated filesn bit dblclicking the app file works fine on 10.6->10.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NSPreferredScrollerStyleDidChangeNotification notification is only available in OSX 10.7 and later, as noted at the bottom of this page:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSScroller_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Qt will conditionally compile OS X 10.7 APIs if MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_7. See e.g.:

http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/blobs/b9826799405293ee5969015eed37957daad198ee/src/widgets/styles/qmacstyle_mac.mm

Possibly the version of Qt you are using was not compiled with the 10.6 SDK.

There is a known issue: "To use Qt on or for 10.6, you need to build Qt yourself on a 10.6 machine":

http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt500KnownIssues

Comment: Ok, I will build Qt5 on snowleopard, will be back in half an hour with the results. can I use the buildedQT5 in 10.8 or do I need to stay on 10.6 to develop the app?

Comment: @VincentDuprez sorry I don't know the answer to that.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Qt 5.1 this is a known issue with macdeployqt, it does not correct linked library paths on the executable, you can see it by yourself with

```
otool -L <executable>
```

You can either switch back to Qt 5.1.0-rc1 or in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475788/qt-5-1-and-mac-bug-making-macdeployqt-not-working-properly) there is a workaround with a script that will fix the problem for you.

Comment: Sorry to tell but I have the exact same results with 5.1.0 RC1 I used the prebuild libraries

Comment: Can you please post output of otool -L <executable> after macdeployqt?

Comment: too large to post as comment, I added this in the original Question

Answer (score 0):

The only way to run your application on Mac OS 10.6 with Qt 5 is to configure Qt with -no-c++ parameter. Compiling Qt on 10.6 is not an option for me, because there would be no Retina support.

The correct workaround is:

Mac OS 10.7 + Qt 5.2.0 + xcode 4.6 + configure with -no-c++11 parameter

PS. Use Vmware with 10.7 to compile Qt. Develop and deploy your app on any Mac OS X (10.9.1)

Comment: I compiled Qt on 10.6 and used this one on 10.9 but the app crashes all the time, like when handling the 'open file' dialog and so.. No issue when coupling Qt in Maverick..

Comment: Well that crash could be anything. Qt5 does compile on 10.6 and apps can be deployed without a problem

Comment: This is our setup: OS X 10.8.5 + Qt 5.2.1 + Xcode 5.0 + ./configure -no-c++11 -arch i386 -platform macx-clang-32 -sdk macosx10.6 -> works fine here.