# Clang++ and `-mmacosx-version-min=10.6`

Tags: c++, macos, c++11

dummy.cpp:

```
#include <functional>

void foo(std::function<void(void)> f) {}
```

And the compile command:

```
clang++  -c  -mmacosx-version-min=10.6  -std=c++11  dummy.cpp -o dummy.o
```

That fails with various errors (`std::function` is unknown). However, without `-mmacosx-version-min=10.6`, it works fine.

Why is that? Can I somehow get C++11 support with `-mmacosx-version-min=10.6`?

---

My current workaround: Use Boost instead for such containers, e.g. `boost::function`. Other syntactic stuff from C++11 can be used without issues.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get back c++0x/c++11 support for Mac OS X 10.6 deployment using Xcode 4.6.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494513/how-do-i-get-back-c0x-c11-support-for-mac-os-x-10-6-deployment-using-xcode-4)

Comment: @Petesh: Is it? I'm not using `-stdlib=libc++`. It should all be header-only, shouldn't it?

Comment: If you're using XCode 5 (which you probably are), then it uses that libc++ by default.

Comment: @Petesh: I used that compile command as-is (i.e. in console).

Comment: Marshal Clow has some good reading on Apple's runtime change. See [What’s up with TR1? (and C++11, and libc++)](http://cplusplusmusings.wordpress.com/author/mtclow/).

Comment: @noloader: How is that related?